# Google Site third party domain verification fails | The required DNS TXT record is propagated even then verification is failing

Tags: dns, domain-registration, google-sites, site-verification, dns-lookup

Similar question has been asked [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/73081980?hl=en) and many other places. However, it doesn't match my issue exactly. I am first describing the situation with screenshots, then below it I mention my question and then further I have provided some additional information.

**Situation**:

1. I have bought a domain from Domain.com. I am using the steps and info from the following screenshot. [image: image 1]
2. I have made both the CNAME and TXT record entry in my DNS.  I ran `dig MY_DOMAIN any`, and I do not see the CNAME there but I can see the TXT record in the return [image: Image 2]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bya2K.png). However, the verification is still failing for the TXT record method as well.

**Questions:**

1. Please see the following image, [image: image3]. It says that the Google didn't find the TXT record. But as I already mentioned that I can see that in return of the `dig <DOMAIN> any`. Why this discrepency?
2. I read [this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/73081980?hl=en) answer and it is talking about a potential conflict due to a CNAME record. Should, I delete CNAME record from my DNS entry as TXT is anyways visible. Will this help?

Please feel free to get back to me with questions.

**Additional Info**:

1. I do not see the TXT record in return of `dig <DOMAIN>`. It is only visible when I use the option ​`any` ​with the `​dig` ​command. . Can this a source of error?
2. While adding the records, I first added the TXT and tried to verify. When it didn't work then I tried CNAME as well.

**Image descriptions**:

Image 1: The white background one. It shows the Instructions on how to verify a third party domain.

Image 2: The black background one. It shows the results of dig.

Image 3: Error on Google

Comment: @PatrickMevzek What does "dig ANY" do?

I am not sure how this verification processes will work, so I didn't share the domain. I tried avoiding sharing the personal information. But I did mention please ask for anything needed. If you need you can simply ask for the real domain name. What's the big deal in it?

Could you please specify why not to use images? Is that a community guidelines? I think the screenshots help in explaining the problem.

Comment: Screenshots images are just fine and often the best way to illustrate problems.      If a screenshot contains only text, it is better to paste the text into your question.  That way people answering the question and quote the text or modify it without having to type it out. Text can also be found with site search or external search engines so that people with similar problems can find it. For example, screen shots of configuration files are much worse than adding the text of configuration files. Screenshots of error messages can be helpful, but the text of the error message should be typed in.

Comment: We usually discourage actual site names here because `example.com` is often good enough to illustrate a problem and it won't be considered spam.     In general, questions should be self-contained enough that we shouldn't have to check the actual site to answer it.   When the site demonstrates a problem that isn't clear from the question, the question is unlikely to be useful to others in the future, especially after the site is fixed.   That being said, when it is very difficult to show the problem without naming the site, or if somebody asks for the name, it is fine to provide it.

Comment: imo DNS Verificaction can take a few minutes....sometimes. - Have you tried other method of verification?

Comment: @AurelioJimenez, DNS verification by TXT record was not working even after 40 hours. The corresponding TXT record was visible at DNS checkers. Finally, I  used CNAME verification. TXT verification still didn't work.